# Creating a list of dictionaries from a list of list

Tags: python

I'm currently stuck facing some issue with creating a list of dictionaries from a list of lists.
I'm confused with how to append each dictionary to empty list(not in my code). I've known there should be some code after loop processing, but I wasn't able to find out what it is.

```
l_members = [['Jhon', '19', 'male'],
       ['Takeru', '20', 'male'],
       ['Yuri', '22', 'female']
      ]

d_members = {}

for i in range(len(l_members)):
  d_members['name'] = l_members[i][0]
  d_members['age'] = l_members[i][1]
  d_members['sex'] = l_members[i][2]
  l_members.append(d_members)

print(d_members)
```

Here's a result of print(d_members)

```
{'name': 'Yuri', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'female'}
```

my expectation of the result is like below

```
[{'name': 'Jhon', 'age': '19', 'sex': 'male'},
 {'name': 'Takeru', 'age': '20', 'sex': 'male'},
 {'name': 'Yuri', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'female'}]
```

I would appreciate your help, thanks:)

Comment: It's because you're appending to the `l_members` variable but you're only printing the `d_members` variable, so it simply prints the final value of `d_members` (i.e. the last record "Yuri"). Additionally, you'll robably find out that the previous records still exist when you print `l_members`, so you'll have to either remove the initial entries once you're done with the for loop, override the value for each iteration of the for loop or store the results in a new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- print the list, not the dict you created `print(l_members)`
- create `d_members` in the loop, to avoid using the same again and again
- then reassign to the `i` box, don't `append` because it'll only add it

```
for i in range(len(l_members)):
    d_members = {}
    d_members['name'] = l_members[i][0]
    d_members['age'] = l_members[i][1]
    d_members['sex'] = l_members[i][2]
    l_members[i] = d_members
print(l_members)
```

---

Here are some shorten ways with `enumerate`, I put some to show you the possiblities

```
for i in range(len(l_members)):
    l_members[i] = {'name': l_members[i][0], 'age': l_members[i][1], 'sex': l_members[i][2]}

for i, member in enumerate(l_members):
    l_members[i] = {'name': member[0], 'age': member[1], 'sex': member[2]}

for i, (name, age, sex) in enumerate(l_members):
    l_members[i] = {'name': name, 'age': age, 'sex': sex}
```

---

You can also use a `list-comprehension` to avoid using the indices and rebuilt directly the list, along with `dict+zip` to create the dict :

```
l_members = [dict(zip(['name', 'age', 'sex'], member)) for member in l_members]
# another one
l_members = [{'name': name, 'age': age, 'sex': sex} for (name, age, sex) in l_members]
```

Comment: I've tried to use enumerate, but I sadly couldn't make it. Is the latter two with list comprehension recommended over the formers?

Comment: @t0j1 using a list comprehension is kinf of recommanded for the nice syntax, for simple code

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a list comprehension might work:

```
d_members = [
   { 'name': name, 'age': age, 'sex': sex } 
   for name, age, sex in l_members
]
```

Comment: Using list comprehension should be quite fast. Nice one. +1

Comment: I didn't know how I should use list comprehension until you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in the comments, this is because your last line of code which prints the value actually prints the *`d_members`* variable which will be the last value of the for-loop. You should instead be printing out the *`l_members`* variable which you appended the values to in your for-loop.

Additionally, you'll robably find out that the previous records still exist when you print `l_members`, so you'll have to either:

1. Remove the initial entries once you're done with the for loop (using list slicing):

   ```py
   l_members = l_members[3:]
   ```
2. Override the value for each iteration of the for loop:

   ```py
   l_members[i] = d_members
   ```
3. Or store the results in a new variable:

   ```py
   ld_members = []

   # in your for loop:
   ld_members.append(d_members)
   ```

Comment: I couldn't come up with the idea that I can use list slicing in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the dict to a new list inside the loop as below

```py
list_of_dicts = []
for i in range(len(l_members)):
    d_members = {}
    d_members['name'] = l_members[i][0]
    d_members['age'] = l_members[i][1]
    d_members['sex'] = l_members[i][2]
    list_of_dicts.append(d_members)

print(list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: I shoulda put empty dictionary inside the for-loop and also new empty list before the for-loop.

Comment: Inside the for loop is better in order to avoid duplication of keys somewhere else in the code.